# use :visible variable to target only those items

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The problem:**
I have a jQuery var setup like so:

```
var count = $("#gallery li:visible").length;
alert(count);
```

This finds all the gallery li's that are currently visible on the page. The number changes when the pagination is triggered, as people can select categories.

I want to be able to use this `count` to then look at the 3rd item of every `count` and `addClass` of `end_item` (as i have 3 in a row)

My HTML:

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li class="gallery_image" data-id="" data-type="">
        <img src=""/><div class="thumb_bg"></div>
        <img src="" data-original="" />
    </li>
    <li class="gallery_image" data-id="" data-type="">
        <img src=""/><div class="thumb_bg"></div>
        <img src="" data-original="" />
    </li>
    <li class="gallery_image" data-id="" data-type="">
        <img src=""/><div class="thumb_bg"></div>
        <img src="" data-original="" />
    </li>
    <li class="gallery_image" data-id="" data-type="">
        <img src=""/><div class="thumb_bg"></div>
        <img src="" data-original="" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Currently trying:

```
$('#gallery li').each( function(count) {
    if( count % 3 != 2 )
    return
    $(this).addClass('end')
})
```

I am not going to have exactly 3 on the page, it could be anything from 2 - 12, so i need to find EVERY 3rd item currently visible

**EDIT:**
My code seems to work... however only when the page first loads. If i use a filter item on my gallery, the code is counting the hidden items, even though i am re-calling the jQuery once a filter is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean "the 3rd item of every `count`"? It's just a number.

Comment: Well, i mean, the 3rd item that is currently visible on the page, more specifically, the 3rd item in every row that is currently visible

Comment: Why not just do `$("#gallery li:visible").last().addClass(...` if you only have 3 visible at a time? or maybe even lastChild if there are multiple groups of 3. As you can see, the question needs to be clarified, either with html, or more description.

Comment: please clear the question

Comment: $("#gallery li:visible").eq(2) // this is 3rd item

Comment: Or are you looking for children of `#gallery li`? Some HTML would be nice.

Comment: Yes, HTML would help as well - it looks to me like your code should do exactly like you're asking (except, you're adding class `end` instead of `end_item`)

Comment: All the answers have hinted at it, but not stated it explicitly:  You're not using `:visible` in your javascript at the bottom of the question, even though you say you are at the top of the question

Comment: @Izkata, well spotted!

Comment: @AlexMorrise Heh, unlike my previous comment, the HTML wasn't necessary (if that is the problem).  I'd stepped away from my computer, came back, and took another look.  Sometimes a break is all you need...

Comment: @Mat-visual, check my answer too, I missed it but thought it could be useful for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3xTc2/1/)

```
$('#gallery li:visible').each(function(i) { 
    if (i % 3 == 2) $(this).addClass('end_item');
});
```

When you load more, just be sure to do this:

```
$('.end_item').removeClass('end_item');
//then execute code from above
```

Comment: +1 as I missed this as well.  Alternatively, I'd probably put the `removeClass` in an `else` to keep them together and prevent it from being forgotten about

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work perfectly and it doesn't break when i filter my items like everything else i've tried. Sorry for the messy question!

Comment: @Mat-visual You're a better question-asker than 99% of StackOverflow.  Unfortunately.  ;)

Comment: @Mat-visual, no need to be sorry! You updated your question with useful information and kept up with the people trying to respond. That was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I missed it but could be useful (in future)

```
$('#gallery li:visible').filter(function(i){ return i % 3 == 2; }).addClass('end');
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/RDvRW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#gallery li:visible').each( function(count) {
      if( (count + 1) % 3 == 0 ) {
        $(this).addClass('end');
      }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mGZmy/1/